# Download steam game on mac and pc?

Tags: steam, steam-play

I have a macbook pro and i am looking to get a gaming pc.  Ive downloaded a few games on steam that are mac and windows compatible.  I play them on my mac.  Would i be able to sign into my steam account on my windows pc and download the windows version without having to buy it again?

Comment: @camelCase For what reason are you creating a new tag?  There seems to be no purpose to it.

Comment: @frank - there are a number of questions specific to this feature.  I've tagged what I can find with a simple search.

Comment: @camelCase I don't think there's any need for the tag.  Steam is Steam.  There's nothing this tag provides that the regular Steam tag doesn't.

Comment: @frank - we already have tags for other steam features (family sharing etc).  Sure, its a sub-tag, but this helps break up the expertise.  Not all Steam users will use multiple platforms for example (i.e. plenty of Steam experts that may not know details for this feature).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just download and install the Steam client, and log in and you can download your games without any issue.

Comment: ...if a game is SteamPlay enabled.

Comment: @Powerlord that's explicit in the question as written.

Comment: No it isn't.  Civilization IV is a good example of a non-SteamPlay title on Steam available for PC and Mac.

Comment: @Powerlord But it says "SteamPlay" right on the Civ4 Steam store page?

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to activate your account and download/install your games on as many machines as you want. But the usage of a steam account is restricted to only one machine a time.

You are not allowed to play games on multiple machines simultaneously! This restriction is also technically enforced. As noted by Nolonar in the comments you can be lgged in on multiple machines at the same time.

Comment: Ever since Steam allows streaming games from one machine to the next, the restriction has been removed. You can now log in on multiple machines simultaneously, although the restriction might still apply if you try to *play* games.

Comment: @Nolonar You are totally right, I mixed that up with its past behaviour and I updated my answer accordingly.